# Do I have 2 routers for my wireless network?

Tags: wifi, time-capsule, router

I use an Airport Time Capsule and have a wireless router. Which one should I use for Wi-fi and how do I know which one I am using now? Thank you.

MacBook Pro 11,3 with Retina display; OS X Mavericks (10.9.5); Airport Time Capsule 802.11ac; Actiontec GT784WNV Router

Comment: How did you set up your Time Capsule?  Open Airport Utility on your Mac to see the settings.  Applications > Utilities > Airport Utility

Comment: Which is your modem plugged into? Look for a wan port on the back.

Comment: Is the Actiontec GT784WNV Router your Wireless DSL Modem Router for Verizon (or other ISP)?  Anyway depending on how the Airport Time Capsule is configured you could connect to it or the Actiontec GT784WNV Router.  Check to see what the Gateway Address of your Wi-Fi Adapter is and then use Network Utility > Netstat to get the MAC Address of the Gateway and then look on the Actiontec GT784WNV Router as it should display on a tag, probably on the bottom, what its MAC Address is and if it matches then your connected to it and then if not check the same on the Airport Time Capsule.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you have Verizon (FiOS) for your service provider, as they use Actiontec routers.  Another router (such as an Airport Time Capsule) can be connected to your Actiontec router, but you cannot substitute another router in place of your Actiontec router.

I recommend turning off WiFi on your Actiontec router, as it has known security issues which enable it to be easily hacked into.  For example, WEP cannot be disabled.  Your ATC can be used as a WiFi "access point" instead, providing superior security and speed.

To know whether you are connected to your ATC, you could try unplugging it to see if you still have access through your Actiontec.

To configure your Actiontec and ATC together, as I've described, is too complex to explain here, as you seem to be a novice user based upon your past questions.  You can be forgiven for not knowing the differences between modems, routers, gateways, LANs, WANs, etc.  Such things are complicated, and weren't designed to be user-friendly.